# Security: How come we still hear about many stack execution security flaws?

Tags: security, exploit, aslr, nomachine-nx, dep

Security: How come we still hear about many stack execution security flaws even though mechanisms such as [NX bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) and [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) exist so many years ? 
Have hackers found ways to circumvent these ?

When looking through relatively recent fixed security flaws in MS and Adobe you can still find exploits that give the attacker control of your system - doesn't this imply running code on stack via buffer overrun (which can't be done with DEP/NX/ASLR)?

Comment: note: found [this article](http://uninformed.org/?v=2&a=4) from 2005 showing methods to bypass hardware DEP, in brief, MS gave the possibility to disable NX/DEP for an already running process from another user space address. But using ASLR this isn't feasible ... And also I hope they manged to fix this ability in the past 6-7 years since the article ... So I am still looking for an answer ...

Comment: [Return Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) discusses why, for instance, `NX` isn't a 100% cure-all. Most of these defenses "raise the bar" on a flaw being exploitable, rather than preventing it completely.

Comment: probably best asked on http://s.tk/security